# How to display a point cloud in Unreal Engine?

Tags: unreal-engine4

I'm attempting to display a point cloud in Unreal Engine using the technique described in [this UE4 forum post](https://forums.unrealengine.com/showthread.php?91501-How-to-place-single-GPU-particles-at-specified-locations&p=428488&viewfull=1#post428488).

I think I followed the description, but I'm not getting any points displayed. The code¹²³⁴ is [here](https://github.com/geary/UnrealBunny). Any ideas on what I got wrong would be much appreciated!

¹ "Code" is a bit of a misnomer, since I didn't write any actual code here, just strung stuff together in the Unreal Editor with Blueprints and the Cascade particle system editor using the instructions in the forum post.

² A secondary question would be how to do this in Unreal using pure C++ code instead of Blueprints and Cascade. For my purposes this would make things much easier. But since the forum post used the visual editors I figured I would try to get that working first.

³ Really off topic but I have to vent: I wish the Unreal Engine peer-help community revolved around sharing actual code, and especially sharing actual working projects, instead of forum posts with incomplete instructions describing how to do something in the GUI that you just *might* get working if you already know what you're doing. It makes it a tough way to learn!

⁴ I also realize that Stack Overflow wants to see code in the question itself and not just a link. But given the nature of the "code" involved, that wasn't possible. Sorry! :-)